# What is the purpose of npm link and how to use it in React JS Projects?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-link

As I am new to React JS and Node JS, I am unable to understand the purpose of npm link and how to use it in React JS Projects even from the npm documentation. It is appreciable to explain the same with example.

Comment: You don't use it with React project. It's used for creating libraries

Comment: I need to use the node_module packages (which are installed globally) in my react js project without installing the required packages locally in the project. What should I do about it? Is any way this NPM LINK useful?

Comment: Why don't you install the package locally?

Comment: I am implementing react js projects release via Jenkins in a production environment.  The production environment is restricted from internet access, so cannot use NPM install there. I need to create node_modules as a common artifact and have to refer it in react Js project to create a build.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

```
cd ~/projects/node-redis    # go into the package directory
npm link                    # creates global link
cd ~/projects/node-bloggy   # go into some other package directory.
npm link redis
```

Comment: In this command "npm link redis", from where redis come?

Answer (score 0):

İ think you can create your own npm repository on your intranet. Npm alreay have a solution about that. And a private npm resity example is [bit.dev](https://bit.dev) you can check this.

Comment: I am thinking that a private npm registry is for our custom shareable packages/ modules. But how to refer already available npm packages which are required for my react js project? Should I add those node_modules into the private npm registry?

Comment: yes the manager copy all npm packages i assume.or you can configure it to get some packages which all depend you.

Comment: As there will be many React JS projects, is it advisable to have common node_modules for all the projects? If I use a common registry, I need to update it if any version of the modules changes. Right?

Comment: i dont know about details about but you can check nexus repository manager to get more info